# Help ID this distinctive 70s/80s pulp sci fi novel

Tags: story-identification

I'm searching for a 70's/80's dark Sci-fi novel about a cop/detective in the future chasing a serial killer with an alien insectoid sidekick...

It's a hardboiled paperback about a human detective chasing a serial killer across the galaxy and between planets. The serial killer is human but had an alien henchman that looked like a 7ft tall praying mantis and would eat people as payment. 
Gritty, noir-ish, full of sex and violence. Possibly from the early 70's to the mid 80's from maybe Tor or Ballantine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I know the book you're talking about and actually saw a copy in a used book store a couple years ago and almost bought it.  The front cover has the two of them on it, I think - him looking like a detective, maybe holding a gun, and the praying mantis side kick.  I just can't remember the name... I'll keep looking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply was there anything else you recollect about the book that would assist with the search, e.g: publisher, era, cover art, blurb, synopsis, character names, galaxy names, series name, title, author, length, genre, tropes etc?

Comment: The closest fit to date has been The Antenna Syndrome by Alan Marks which features a mantid henchman but does not feature a lot of the other characters mentioned, ie serial killer etc